# infinite http request loop when it's inside a data service observable and its response used to call a function inside the outer data service (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want some data that's inside a data service and is an observable, when I subscribe to the data, I then make an HTTP request and send the data along with it. When the response is received, I then subscribe to it and try to call a function inside the same data service. Here's the code:

```
// data service //
this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((shared_data) => {

  // http request //
  this.httpService
    .send_analysis_options(shared_data)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {

      // data service change function //
      this.data.changeMessage(response)
    });
});
```

the problem is when this code block gets called, it suddenly sends infinite requests and get into an infinite loop. When I remove the line where it calls `changeMessage` function, everything works. Please help me solve this problem. THANKS

UPDATE:
code inside data service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  template: any = {
    filename: '',
    submit_id: 0,
    Referer: '',
    'network-routing': '',
    package: '',
    priority: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    filesize: 0,
    package_extension: '',
    'new_key': '',
    'new_value': '',
    'remote-control': false,
    'enable-injection': false,
    'process-memory-dump': false,
    'full-memory-dump': false,
    'enforce-timeout': false,
    'simulated-human-interaction': false,
    mime: '',
    machines: [],
    selected_machine: ''
  };

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<object>(this.template);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  changeMessage(coming_message: any) {
    for (let x in coming_message) {
      this.template[x] = coming_message[x];
    }
    this.messageSource.next(this.template);
    console.log(this.template)
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you also share the code inside the `data` service

Answer (score 1):

Your piece of code can be read as : "when the message change, send some data then update the current message" which, of course, lead to an infinite loop.

I guess this code is called after some user interaction (ex: click), you should immediatly unsubscribe after retrieving the current message value like this :

```
this.data.currentMessage.pipe(first()).subscribe((shared_data) => {/*..*/});
```

Also, don't forget to unsubscribe your `send_analysis_options` subscribtion as it will lead to memory leak (with a `first()` or `unsubscribe`).